# Returning all clusters without having duplicate items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of clusters data. Each cluster contains a set of items, sample below:

Cluster 1) (1,1), (1,2)

Cluster 2) (2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)

Cluster 3) (3,1),(3,2),(3,3)

Cluster 4) (4,3),(4,4),(4,6),(4,7)

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'Item': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ID      Item
1        1
1        2
2        2
2        3
2        4
2        5
3        1
3        2
3        3
4        3
4        4
4        6
4        7
```

I need to get at least one item from each cluster in the final data frame considering the fact that the final data frame must not contain the same items, exmaple of desired output data frame:

```
ID      Item
1        1
1        2
2        4
2        5
3        3
4        6
4        7
```

I've tried doing the below where it keeps the first occurance but it gives the below results where it dropped records for ID 3 given they all apear before in the dataframe:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Item', keep='first')

ID      Item
1        1
1        2
2        3
2        4
2        5
4        6
4        7
```

Then if i try keeping last occurance like below, it'll end up dropping ID 1 because all its items appeared later in the dataframe:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Item', keep='last')

ID      Item
2        5
3        1
3        2
4        3
4        4
4        6
4        7
```

Do you guys have any ideas on how could i do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Alright, this is not a problem to remove the duplication from the column in your data frame.** Your problem was not descriptive enough to help me to propose a solution faster. **Look the problem is as the following:**

**Given four clusters of data (ID in your data frame). Each cluster contains a set of items (your Item in the data frame).**

Cluster 1) (1,1), (1,2)

Cluster 2) (2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)

Cluster 3) (3,1),(3,2),(3,3)

Cluster 4) (4,3),(4,4),(4,6),(4,7)

**We are supposed to have at least one item from each cluster in the final data frame considering the fact that the final data frame must not contain the same items (sth that you've indicated as duplications).** Clear?

Example: From cluster one, put both items into the data frame. (1,1)(1,2)

From cluster two, put item 3, 4, 5 which are (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)

However, when you see cluster three, you might notice that you've already had items from this cluster in your final data frame (items 1 and 2 in the first cluster) and (item 3 in the second one). But, as far as you are supposed to consider at least one item from each cluster, you can remove item 3 from cluster two and put item 3 from cluster three in your final data frame. (This is the point) let's choose (3,3)

From Cluster four, you can take (4,4),(4,6),(4,7) items.

Now, experts in python can help us to see how this can be effectively written in python to find a solution autonomously.

Comment: thank you very much. In fact, you've articulated the problem way better than I have, perhaps I was more focused on the technical side of explaining it and forgot to look at the upper level of what the problem is and how to better communicate it to viewers.

Comment: Thank your for your feedback, what I suggest you is to edit the problem description in your post to keep others from being confused while they go through your problem.

Comment: Good shout @Navid, I will edit it to better reflect what the problem is, i may use parts of the text you've had up there if that's okay with you?

Comment: Sure, no problem use any part desires for you